# Windows Form Size changes at run time automatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am developing an project in VB using .NET and One of my form is resizing it self at runtime. My other form are perfect but only my one page, which I made is a login page, gets resize at runtime.

[My configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xIa.png)

Comment: You have a control on this form that declares the app to be dpiAware.  On recent Win10 version that instantly disables dpi virtualization and changes the window size.  Very naughty, but too common, WPF controls do this for example.  Other than not using it, best thing to do is [stay ahead of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form to be resized, try setting the AutoSize form property to False.